# Good software for technical documentation?

Tags: documentation-generator, documentation-viewer

I would like to create some technical documentation. My requirements are that:

- I can run it on a server as a website.
- It is editable as some sort of markdown and editable by a fairly non-technical user.
- There is a contents page structure that is referrable to.
- Exportable to a set of HTML pages.

The closest I have come to this is Dokuwiki, where I create a contents page as a homepage. This is fine but I want a more restrictive environment so that pages can't hide. What I want to create is something that looks like:

[image: Desired software look]

This has a structured, dropdown contents down the left hand side and simple text and images in the main window. If I could click on these sections and edit like a wiki, then I'd be sold. I want something really simple that will allow me to scale out to a full set of documentation.

Does anyone know of something like this?